# JSON LOCAL : CANT LOAD DATA FROM LISTTILE flutter

Tags: json, flutter, dart, local

is something wrong with my code ? it only load the error in listtile. is there anyway to fix it ? i already convert the json to dart by using dataclass

```
class _PlantPageState extends State<PlantPage> {
  
  

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Scaffold(
    body: FutureBuilder<List<Plants>>(
      future: PlantsApi.getPlantsLocally(context),
      builder:(context, snapshot) {
        final plants = snapshot.data;
        switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
          case ConnectionState.waiting:
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          default:
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Center(child: Text('Some error'),);
          }
          else {
            return buildPlants(plants!);
          }

Widget buildPlants(List<Plants> plants) => 
ListView.builder(
  
  itemCount: plants.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    final plant = plants[index];
    return 
    
    ListTile (
      title: Text(plant.name ?? "Name"),
    );
  }
  );
```

here is my fetchdata from json

```
class PlantsApi {
  static Future<List<Plants>> getPlantsLocally(BuildContext context) async {
    final assetBundle = DefaultAssetBundle.of(context);
    final data = await assetBundle.loadString('assets/plants.json');
    final body = json.decode(data);

    return body.map<Plants>((e) => Plants.fromJson(e)).toList();
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please post the error log?

Comment: there is no error log. but when im running the app. the only thing they choose is 
 if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Center(child: Text('Some error'),);

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the assets enabled in the pubspec.yaml? If not, that could be the problem

Comment: yes sir. hard to find the error. why it only pick   if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Center(child: Text('Some error'),);